# UK stocks institutional owners and transactions

Tags: stocks, investing, united-kingdom

For stocks listed on the FTSE, is it possible to find out who are the institutional investors that own a particular stock and what are the percentages?

I know that we can see the trades being conducted on a particular stock, but do they disclose which trade is made by institutional investors? If not, then why?

The only information I have regarding the questions above is just from the RNS (Regulatory News Service) when an institutional investor reports on a trade conducted that crosses a certain threshold on stock ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FT, YAHOO etc provides such information. As an example check out [TESCO on FT](https://markets.ft.com/data/equities/tearsheet/profile?s=TSCO:LSE) and so does [TESCO on Yahoo](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/mh?s=TSCO.L)

Comment: Thanks! I did check FT before asking, but I guess I was looking at the wrong stocks that have no institutional investor section.

Comment: Any idea if this information is voluntarily disclosed by the company or it is enforced by regulations?